# Is it possible to publish a stand alone c# application to Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, centos

I am trying to publish a C# .net core console app I made, to a Linux machine running Centos 7 64 bit. Currently, I am publishing the app using the command:`dotnet publish -c release -r contos.7-x64`. Unfortunately, it appears as though publishing in this way requires .net core to be installed on the target machine. Is it possible to do this where I do not need to install anything on the machine that I am publishing to?

Comment: _"it appears as though publishing in this way requires core to be installed on the machine that I am trying to release to"_ - Why do you conclude this?

Comment: Are you using the correct id [(see the the list of IDs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids). Centos is listed under the linux-x64 id, have you tried using that?

Comment: I tested publishing (`dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64`) a simple console application to an Ubuntu machine without .NET Core installed and it worked just fine. I don't see why Centos would be any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was that the project was not compiling to core 2. Rather, the project was compiling to version 1. After making this change, the published project was able to run on Centos.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Core 2.2 you can create a self-contained app (i.e. not requiring .NET Core runtime installed on host machine) with this command `dotnet publish -r centos.7-x64 -c Release --self-contained`. It'll produce executable and a lot of dependencies.

In .NET Core 3 you can compress all dependencies into a single file `dotnet publish -r centos.7-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`. You can also add flag `/p:PublishTrimmed=true` to reduce executable size by [tree trimming](https://github.com/mono/linker/blob/master/src/ILLink.Tasks/README.md).

More details can be found [here](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/create-trimmed-self-contained-executable-in-net-core-3-0/)  and [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx).